# Setting Buttons and EditText theme to Holo after implementing HoloEverywhere and SherlockActionBar?

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, android-holo-everywhere

Finally I was able to implement successfully the libraries `Sherlock` and `Holo` .
Now after creating my own project, and setting in the manifest file the theme to:
 `android:theme="@style/Theme.Sherlock.Light"`

I tried to run the application on my `Android 2.3.6`; the `Button` and the `EditText` do still have the old theme. How can I change those themes to Holo after all that tiring implementation?

I saw somewhere that i should set `android:theme="@style/Holo.Theme.Sherlock.Light"` but I can't see any of this. An error is occuring in the manifest once it's being set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use only themes @style/Holo.Theme, @style/Holo.Theme.Light, @style/Holo.Theme.Light.DarkActionBar.
It's already have a sherlock dependency.

ps: you not have fully-integrated holoeverywhere. org.holoeverywhere.app.Activity throw exception if you not use HE themes.